# Http Headers: Redirected because not allowed?

Tags: http, http-headers

What's the correct header to say 'you are not authenticated/authorized to access the content of this URL, so I'm redirecting you somewhere else (eg: login page)'.

Is it fine to just use a 302 ? Or maybe a 307 ?

Answer (score 0):

[401 is unauthorized](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html), there is no unauthorized and redirection (301/307) in the same HTTP status.

Comment: Okay but what's the correct header for this situation then? For example, I can tell 301 shouldn't be used, because it would confuse search engines. Should I pick 302 then?

Comment: I assume 401 is correct, you are not authenticated. On the page itself you can show the login form. Or a link to the homepage or the login form.

Answer (score 0):

I'd issue a 401 with a link in the body and a timed javascript redirect.